# Email Settings - unclear description for "Community Milestones"

Tags: feature-request, email, help-improvement

This On/Off toggle in account Email Settings:

> Community Milestones
>
> Notifications about bounties, reputation and more. Hint: sometimes involves swag.

For user's **bounties**, I get it. 
 But I don't get it for the rest. I had this setting enabled, and never received any email about **reputation** steps. I don't get what **more** is supposed to include. 
 And for **swag**... please, helpful descriptions... I like fun, but it's not the place.

What I wanted to determine, without success, is if this setting is for spam or ham.

So, please clarify the description of this setting.

Comment: Pretty sure the only swag you can get is the 100K swag... and apparently now a 1M podcast.

Comment: @Catija Stack (Overflow/Exchange) (the company) sometimes hold swag contests.

Comment: Sorry I'm 30+ years old, I don't know what is a "swag" or a "swag contest", and I shouldn't have to guess this in my mail settings...

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-does-swag-mean

Comment: I mean... I'm 30+ years old and I _do_ know how to google a term that I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: I shouldn't have to google a setting description, and *guess* what it might relate to. See the uncertainty in above comments. Also, there was a detailed comment explaining a possible meaning of the term, sadly it has been removed.